# Maxvalue of Growth (nummerical) on Excel or other program

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, logistic-regression

I need to solve this problem numerically:
$$
n'(t)=0.12\left(1-\frac{1}{10000}\cdot n(t)\right)\cdot n(t)-x,\\
 n(0)=2000.
$$

I need to find the right $x$ so that $n'(t)=0$.
I know that the right answer is $x=192$ but how do I proceed the task? In what program can I set up the equation so that it tries all the values of $x$ and shows that when $x=192$ then $n'(t)=0$ ???

Comment: You can actually solve this by hand though. Do you specifically have to use a software?

Comment: @Karn Watcharasupat Yupp but I get a wrong answer, when I solve it by hand I get x=288, the right answer is x=192.

Comment: are you familiar with Improved Euler's method?

Comment: Yea  @Karn Watcharasupat

Comment: Are you able to set it up in excel?

Comment: But I think that I am supposed to solve it numerically

Comment: IEM is a numerical method...

Comment: Thats the problem, I really have no Idea how I should set it up. So it tries diffrent numbers for the x and finds the one that gives n'(t)=0. I must find a program that solves it numerically

Comment: If $n'(t)=0$, then $n'(0)=0$.

Comment: By the way, there is an analytical solution for $n(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem without any numerical method:

To have $n'(0)=0$ and $n(0)=0$ you need:
$$0=n'(0)=0.12\left(1-\frac{1}{10000}\cdot n(0)\right)\cdot n(0)-x=0.12\left(1-\frac{1}{10000}\cdot 2000\right)\cdot 2000-x$$
i.e:$$0=192-x$$

Comment: But The problem is that I have to solve it numerically also ....

Comment: Do you know any way to set it up so it shows diffrent solutions for n'(t) based on x? So it also includes x=192, n'(t)=0 in the list?

Comment: As pointed out in the comments you can use an euler method to compute $n'$ from $n(0)$ and $x$, is it what you want ?

Comment: I need to set up a list with values of x and n'(t) in a program like excel based on my ekvation, and try x= different numbers from 1 to 200 to recive output values for n'(t).

Comment: By $n'(t)$ do you mean $n'(0)$ or the function $t \mapsto n'(t)$ ?

Comment: n is the population, t is the hours. n'(t) indicates the growth. So based on the ekvation above. I need to nummericly find a value for x so n'(t)=0. That means a max value of x so that n'(t) is still positive